# Covering number of smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, approximation-theory, packing-and-covering

Let $(\mathcal{X},d)$ be a space of function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ where $d=\|  \cdot \|_\infty$  (i.e., $d(f)= \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|$ ).

Let $D_\alpha f= \frac{\partial^\alpha}{ \partial x_1^{p_1} .... \partial x_d^{p_d} }$ where $\alpha=p_1 +...+ p_d$ where $p_i$'s are non-negative integers and  we let $D^0f =f$.

Suppose we consider the following set
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_\beta = \{ f:  \| D_\alpha f \|_\infty<c_\alpha, \forall \alpha\le \beta \} .
\end{align}

I am interested in an upper bound on the covering number of $\mathcal{F}_\beta$. Given the history of covering numbers and metric entropy, I would think that this result exists. However, I just cannot find anywhere a firm upper bound.